# Did I take the appropriate action in dupehammering this question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I recently dupehammered (verb: to close a question with the dupehammer) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247017/printing-a-sentence-and-a-list-in-python) as a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list). The user wasn't too happy about it. Was it an appropriate dupe close or did I make a mistake?

In reality he had two issues: one of how to join the list, and another of how to print both strings. The latter [also already has a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python) though I only figured this out later. I thought joining the list was the hard part and he could figure out the rest on his own.

I could have easily written a nice answer answering the question exactly, it being a very simple question. It was a good question otherwise, explaining exactly what he needed and what he already tried. Both me and the user would have been happier. And it seems the net effect would have been the same had I done that vs. had I linked him to both questions - to answer his question - yet it would have been less conflict-inducing to just answer it rather than close it as a dupe.

I know what it feels like to feel like someone is hypervigilant in criticizing/downvoting/closing my questions and being apparently unhelpful. This time I found myself playing the role of that hypervigilant guy, and I didn't quite like it.

Comment: SO users are never happy about it.  Short from the highly visible compliment for not being able to google yourself out of a paper bag, always high odds that they don't understand the linked Q+A or it isn't *exactly* word-for-word the same.  Or the 8 minutes this person needed to understand the Q+A was twice too long.  Now they have a single person to complain at.  You.  They always complain.

Comment: Sod 'em.  Swing that hammer.  Carry on closing.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with appropriate application of Mjolnir.

Comment: @jdphenix: Though sometimes adding the appropriate LART-treatment to the poster afterwards wouldn't hurt...

Comment: How can I see original question? I guess now that it's been dupehammered, the 'this question' link above doesn't work for me.

Comment: "LART-treatment" means what, asks the n00b.

Comment: @davejagoda No, it was still visible while it was closed. It's just since been _deleted._ 10k+ users and mods can see the question still, and the rest of us can if someone decides to add a screenshot.

Comment: @CDC Google LART and BOFH.

Comment: Lol.  Got it.  Thought it was SO specific.

Comment: Your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247017/printing-a-sentence-and-a-list-in-python#comment54296336_33247017) could have been extended there to include the complete code (as it was a one liner). Something like *You want to turn the list into one string where the elements are joined by strings and then print that resulting string. Do `print "I would like", ", ".join(food).` And for more details see the linked question*. This could've prevented the OP from pinging you again and again. But regarding the hammerin, it is a perfect find. Something which I would have done too. Regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A good Stack Overflow question contains just a single problem statement, one which is not answered by any other question on Stack Overflow. As near as I can tell, the question in question fails to meet either of these criteria. And since it fails the second criteria, it's eligible to be closed as a duplicate.

You shouldn't feel bad about complying with the standards of the site. As others have pointed out, people very often complain any time something they perceive as negative happens to them. That's more a reflection on them, than on you.

So why I am even answering? Because I will also point out: Stack Overflow has a community-driven mechanism for overriding your dupe hammer. Indeed, in what has probably been over a hundred applications of my dupe hammer, I have twice (that I can recall) closed as a duplicate a question that was later reopened by the community. In one case, I disagree with the judgment, but I accept that I will not always agree with the community. In the other case, the community's judgment was sound; I read through the question too quickly, and misinterpreted what was the core of the problem.

In either case, you've got the community there to watch your back. **You should of course always be careful in the application of the dupe hammer.** And it's even reasonable to at least for a moment reconsider if the OP presents a reasonable objection. But beyond that, feel confident in your actions and trust that if you have somehow made a mistake you yourself are unable to recognize, the community will be right there to help rectify a mistake if made (and occasionally even override your decision even if one wasn't made).

If the community doesn't speak up, odds are very good that you made the correct choice. And not to diminish the value of your question here, but your time is better spent, instead of worrying about your use of the dupe hammer, helping the OP learn how they can research their question, present their separate questions in separate posts (to keep one question from being closed as a duplicate by association with another), and generalize answers to their questions based on identical but superficially-different questions.

(Time-permitting, of course; it's not actually your responsibility to do any of these things, but if you feel you can provide useful, constructive commentary that can guide the user in that direction, you might as well.)

Comment: I like this answer best. It not only addresses the direct issue, but also made me more confident in using the dupe hammer (as there's a community-driven mechanism to override it), and gave me insight into how better to help someone in the situation of having asked a bad question, if I want to spend the time.

Answer (score 21):

It looks fine to me.  The OP has two issues in general - the printing of the list without the brackets, and they must be on Python 2 since they're printing a tuple out.

They're going to be upset that their question wasn't *verbatim* answered by the dupe, but that's a thing that happens.  The crux of the question was well-answered by the duplicate, *and* it does exactly what they want it to, so I don't see any issue with this dupe closing.

Answer (score 8):

I think the real issue here isn't even the dupehammer, it's just the general laziness of OP and his unhappiness and his seemingly immature responses making you feel like anything was your fault and thereby doubting any and all of your actions (including closing it as a dupe).

I personally disliked the entire structure of his 'question' as it seemed more like he hadn't even attempted to read up on any Python and it's general demeanor came off as "I want to do this, I can't do this, tell me how to do this" which isn't even entirely unintentional to me.

Your decision was correct and, going to be blunt here, if he doesn't have half the rest of his brain to put some effort in to actually work something out, his discontent should not make you question the almighty dupehammer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in the question. The duplicate addresses only one issue. The second issue (the difference between `print(a,b)` and `print a, b`) in Python 2 is unaddressed. Both issues are equally trivial. The answer should fix both issues.

A good question should have a single issue but OP might not know beforehand that the code has more than one issue.

The dupe fixes the issue in the title (`",".join`). It is unlikely that somebody will find the question in the hope of fixing the `print(tuple)` issue. OP has received the answer in the comments and therefore there is no point to reopen the question at this point.